# My React Quiz App Results Screen Is Not Rendering - Any Idea Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, render

**General Layout of Quiz:**

I am working on a quiz app that has three distinct components that render to what the user sees - a 'StartScreen', a 'QuestionsScreen', and an 'EndScreen'. For some reason the EndScreen will not render based on the criteria I am giving it.

The different Components are all navigated through the Quiz3 component, which holds the main states for the quiz, which are then passed as props to the other three. The main states that are used to identify which stage of the quiz the user is in are the 'clickBegin' and 'scoredQuiz' states. Those are working fine, because I'm able to navigate through the StartScreen and QuestionsScreen just fine. ***I'm guessing the actual scoring of the quiz is where the system is falling apart.***

**Scoring Logic:**

As the user answers all the questions found in the 'questions' object in the javascript-quiz-3.js file, their answers (which are denoted by the 'type' value found below the text of the particular choice) are iterated into an array that changes the state value of score (found in the functionA-D functions in the main file). That part is working fine, and the array is being filled properly.

When all the questions are 8 questions are answered and we have our complete score array, functionsA-D (depending on what answer is clicked) run the scoreQuiz() function. This function updates the state value of scoredQuiz to true, and calculates most the frequent value that is found in the score array. I'm doing this with a for loop with a compare variable that updates depending on how many times a certain string is found. When the most most frequent string is found, the compare variable is set to the mostFrequentValue variable. That variable then sets the state of mostFrequent.

**What I'm Expecting and Error:**

Hypothetically, depending on what the state value of 'mostFrequent' ends up being, it is supposed to render a different result in the EndScreen component, where 'mostFrequent' is passed as a prop. The logic all seems sound, but when I run the quiz, I get an error that says:

**"Uncaught Error: EndScreen(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."**

My renders and returns are all set up properly, so I don't know what React is detecting. Any thoughts?

**Actual Code:**

***quiz-3.js:***

```
import React from 'react'; 
import TopNavbar from '../navbar';
import {startLabels} from './javascript/javascript-quiz-3'; 
import {questions} from './javascript/javascript-quiz-3';
import {endLabels} from './javascript/javascript-quiz-3'; 
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import {Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Quiz3 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      clickBegin: false,
      scoredQuiz: false,
      currentQuestion: 0,
      score: [],
      mostFrequent: '',
    }
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this); 
    this.changeClicked = this.changeClicked.bind(this); 
    this.scoreQuiz = this.scoreQuiz.bind(this); 
    this.functionA = this.functionA.bind(this);
    this.functionB = this.functionB.bind(this);
    this.functionC = this.functionC.bind(this);
    this.functionD = this.functionD.bind(this); 
  }

  // State Functions

  reset() {
    this.setState({
      currentQuestion: 0,
      score: [],
    })
  }

  changeClicked() {
    if (this.state.clickBegin === false) {
      this.setState({
        clickBegin: true
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        clickBegin: false
      })
    console.log(this.state.clickBegin)
    }
  }

  scoreQuiz() {
      this.setState({
        scoredQuiz: true
      })
      for(var i = 0; i > this.state.score.length; i++) {
        var counts = {}; 
        var compare = 0; 
        var result = this.state.score[i];
        var mostFrequentValue = undefined;

        if (counts[result] === undefined) {
          counts[result] = 1
        }
        else {
          counts[result] = counts[result] + 1
        }

        if (counts[result] > compare) {
          compare = counts[result]; 
          mostFrequentValue = this.state.score[i]; 
        }
      }
      this.setState({
        mostFrequent: mostFrequentValue
      })
  }

  functionA () {
    if(this.state.currentQuestion < 7) {
      this.setState ({
        score: [...this.state.score, questions[this.state.currentQuestion].choiceA.type], 
        currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.currentQuestion >= 7) {
      this.scoreQuiz(); 
    }
    return;
  }

  functionB () {
    if(this.state.currentQuestion < 7) {
      this.setState ({
        score: [...this.state.score, questions[this.state.currentQuestion].choiceB.type], 
        currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.currentQuestion >= 7) {
      this.scoreQuiz(); 
    }
    return;
  }

  functionC () {
    if(this.state.currentQuestion < 7) {
      this.setState ({
        score: [...this.state.score, questions[this.state.currentQuestion].choiceC.type], 
        currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.currentQuestion >= 7) {
      this.scoreQuiz(); 
    }
    return;
  }

  functionD () {
    if(this.state.currentQuestion < 7) {
      this.setState ({
        score: [...this.state.score, questions[this.state.currentQuestion].choiceD.type], 
        currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.currentQuestion >= 7) {
      this.scoreQuiz(); 
    }
    return;
  }

// Different pages rendered depending on state values

  render() {
    if (this.state.clickBegin === false && this.state.scoredQuiz === false) {
      return (
        <div>
          <TopNavbar />
          <div id = "main">
            <StartScreen 
            clickBegin = {this.state.clickBegin}
            scoredQuiz = {this.state.scoredQuiz}
            currentQuestion = {this.state.currentQuestion}
            score = {this.state.score}
            changeClicked = {this.changeClicked} 
            reset = {this.reset} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (this.state.clickBegin === true && this.state.scoredQuiz === false) {
      return (
        <div id = "main">
          <TopNavbar />
          <QuestionsScreen 
            clickBegin = {this.state.clickBegin}
            scoredQuiz = {this.state.scoredQuiz}
            currentQuestion = {this.state.currentQuestion} 
            score = {this.state.score}
            functionA = {this.functionA}
            functionB = {this.functionB}
            functionC = {this.functionC}
            functionD = {this.functionD} />
        </div>
      )
    }

    if (this.state.clickBegin === true && this.state.scoredQuiz === true) {
      return (
        <div>
          <TopNavbar />
            <EndScreen 
              currentQuestion = {this.state.currentQuestion}
              score = {this.state.score}
              mostFrequent = {this.state.mostFrequent}
              scoreQuiz = {this.scoreQuiz} 
              reset = {this.reset}
            />
        </div>
      )
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class StartScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }
  click() {
    this.props.changeClicked();
    this.props.reset(); 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid id = 'start-screen'>
        <Row id = "quiz-title"> 
          <h1> {startLabels[0].title} </h1> 
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <img src = {startLabels[0].imgSrc} /> 
        </Row>
        <Row id = "quiz-description"> 
          <p> {startLabels[0].descrip} </p> 
        </Row>
        <Row id = "begin-quiz" onClick = {this.click}> 
          <p> {startLabels[0].startQuiz} </p> 
        </Row> 
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

class QuestionsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid id = "questions-screen"> 
        <Row id = "question-title"> 
          <p> {questions[this.props.currentQuestion].question} </p> 
        </Row>
        <Row id = "choice-container-1"> 
          <Col id = "choiceA" onClick = {this.props.functionA}> <p> {questions[this.props.currentQuestion].choiceA.choice} </p> </Col>
          <Col id = "choiceB" onClick = {this.props.functionB}> <p> {questions[this.props.currentQuestion].choiceB.choice} </p> </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row id = "choice-container-2">
          <Col id = "choiceC" onClick = {this.props.functionC}> <p> {questions[this.props.currentQuestion].choiceC.choice} </p> </Col>
          <Col id = "choiceD" onClick = {this.props.functionD}> <p> {questions[this.props.currentQuestion].choiceD.choice} </p> </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

class EndScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.mostFrequent === "Warrior") {
      return (
        <Container fluid id = "end-screen"> 
          <Row id = "result"> <h1> {endLabels[0].result} </h1> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-picture"> <img src = {endLabels[0].imgSrc} /> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-description"> <p> {endLabels[0].descrip} </p> </Row>
          <Row id = "take-again" onclick = {this.props.reset}> <p> {endLabels[0].takeAgain} </p> </Row>
        </Container>
      )
    }
    if (this.props.mostFrequent === "Rogue") {
      return (
        <Container fluid id = "end-screen"> 
          <Row id = "result"> <h1> {endLabels[1].result} </h1> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-picture"> <img src = {endLabels[1].imgSrc} /> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-description"> <p> {endLabels[1].descrip} </p> </Row>
          <Row id = "take-again" onclick = {this.props.reset}> <p> {endLabels[1].takeAgain} </p> </Row>
        </Container>
      )
    }
    if (this.props.mostFrequent === "Sorcerer") {
      return (
        <Container fluid id = "end-screen"> 
          <Row id = "result"> <h1> {endLabels[2].result} </h1> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-picture"> <img src = {endLabels[2].imgSrc} /> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-description"> <p> {endLabels[2].descrip} </p> </Row>
          <Row id = "take-again" onclick = {this.props.reset}> <p> {endLabels[2].takeAgain} </p> </Row>
        </Container>
      )
    }
    if (this.props.mostFrequent === "Bard") {
      return (
        <Container fluid id = "end-screen"> 
          <Row id = "result"> <h1> {endLabels[3].result} </h1> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-picture"> <img src = {endLabels[3].imgSrc} /> </Row>
          <Row id = "result-description"> <p> {endLabels[3].descrip} </p> </Row>
          <Row id = "take-again" onclick = {this.props.reset}> <p> {endLabels[3].takeAgain} </p> </Row>
        </Container>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

***quiz-3-javascript.js:***

```
// HTML fill-in for each part of quiz //

export const startLabels = [
  {
    title: "Which RPG class are you?",
    imgSrc: "",
    descrip: "Pick the lock, or break the face?",
    startQuiz: "Start Quiz!",
  },
];

export const questions = [

  {
    question: "Pick your weapon!",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "A stick I found on the ground.",
      type: 'Warrior',
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "I'll just steal if off someone.",
       type: 'Rogue',
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "Green stuff shooting out of my hands.",
       type: 'Sorcerer',
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "My silver tongue.",
       type: 'Bard',
   },
  }, 

  {
   question: "There's an orc guarding the chest you need to get to. Do you...",
   imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
   choiceA: {
     choice: "Throw a rock to distract him and sneak in.",
     type: 'Rogue',
   },
   choiceB: {
      choice: "Smash their face in. And then the chest.",
      type: 'Warrior',
   },
   choiceC: {
      choice: "Convice the orc that you are their chief.",
      type: 'Bard',
   },
   choiceD: {
      choice: "Teleport the chest to you.",
      type: 'Sorcerer',
    },
  }, 

  {
    question: "There's a strange mist washign over you. How do you respond?",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "Perceive what type of magic it is.",
      type: 'Sorcerer',
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "Use the mist to hide.",
       type: 'Rogue',
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "Ready your weapon and know you're going to use it.",
       type: 'Warrior',
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "Find the mist melancholic and beautiful. Get song ideas.",
       type: 'Bard',
   },
  }, 

   {
    question: "You think you got a bad deal from a shopkeeper on a ring you sold. Do you... ?",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "Sneak back in when the shop is closed and take the ring.",
      type: 'Rogue',
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "Threaten the shop owner and note how you can smash their counter.",
       type: 'Warrior'
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "Cast an illusion in the shop that absorbs all metal objects in the shop until the ring is returned.",
       type: 'Sorcerer'
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "Charm the shopkeeper so they give you the ring back.",
       type: 'Bard',
   },
  }, 

  {
    question: "You get ambushed on the way to the city. You are clearly outnumbered.",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "They may have numbers, but I have my axe.",
      type: 'Warrior',
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "Throw a smokebomb down and run to higher ground.",
       type: 'Rogue',
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "Create a ring of fire around you.",
       type: 'Sorcerer',
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "Play the ambush a song. Leave unaffected.",
       type: 'Bard',
   },
  }, 

  {
    question: "What does your ideal world look like?",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "Everyone takes the time to learn.",
      type: 'Sorcerer'
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "Everyone would be honest and direct.",
       type: 'Warrior',
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "Endless beauty.",
       type: 'Bard',
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "Deeper pockets.",
       type: 'Rogue',
   },
  }, 

  {
    question: "The front door is locked. What do you do?",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "Pick the lock of course!",
      type: 'Rogue',
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "Melt the lock.",
       type: 'Sorcerer',
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "It just needs more force!",
       type: 'Warrior',
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "Maybe find the key?",
       type: 'Bard',
   },
  }, 

  {
    question: "Your quest is done. What do you do to unwind?",
    imgSrc: "https://a.wattpad.com/cover/140215314-352-k843958.jpg",
    choiceA: {
      choice: "Flirt with the most beautiful people I can find.",
      type: 'Bard',
    },
    choiceB: {
       choice: "Explore the realm of each element.",
       type: 'Sorcerer',
    },
    choiceC: {
       choice: "Eat as much as I can!",
       type: 'Warrior',
    },
    choiceD: {
       choice: "Find a quiet corner to relax with my treasures.",
       type: 'Rogue',
   },
  },
];

export const endLabels = [
  {
  result: "Warrior",
  imgSrc: "",
  descrip: "No problem can't be solved with my axe.",
  takeAgain: "Take Again!"
  }, 


  {
  result: "Rogue",
  imgSrc: "",
  descrip: "The shadows are my natural home.",
  takeAgain: "Take Again!"
  }, 


  {
  result: "Sorcerer",
  imgSrc: "",
  descrip: "Life, to you, is a world of mysteries to be uncovered.",
  takeAgain: "Take Again!"
  }, 


  {
  result: "Bard",
  imgSrc: "",
  descrip: "The world is boring without a little beauty.",
  takeAgain: "Take Again!"
  }, 

];
```

***navbar.js:***

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import {NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'; 

class TopNavbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar expand = 'lg' bg = 'light' variant = 'light'>
                <Container fluid>
                    <NavDropdown title = "|||" id = "basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item> <Link to = "/"> Quizzes </Link> </NavDropdown.Item> 
                        <NavDropdown.Item> <Link to = "/register"> Register </Link> </NavDropdown.Item> 
                        <NavDropdown.Item> <Link to = "/subscribe"> Subscribe </Link> </NavDropdown.Item> 
                    </NavDropdown>
                    <Link to = "/"> <img alt = 'placeholder'/> </Link>
                    <Link to = "/login"> <Button className = "login"> Login </Button></Link>
                </Container>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default TopNavbar;
```

Comment: did you console.log `this.props.mostFrequent` to see what it actually is?

Comment: No but that is a good idea!

Comment: what does it say?